# NameError in Users#show

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, passenger, production

Showing */home/bdme551/bdme21/app/views/users/show.html.erb* where line #6 raised:

```
undefined local variable or method `size' for #<#<Class:0x007fb271759100>:0x00000003b579a0>
Extracted source (around line #5):

      def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })
        gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
        gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
        image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
      end
    end
```

I'm getting the `NameError`.  Can someone help me, please?  Thanks.

Comment: I added answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `size` with to `options[:size]` because you are passing hash on `options` parameter.

Instead of:

```
gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
```

Try:

```
gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{options[:size]}"
```